# how to combine row that have same date

Tags: php, mysqli

how can i group the same row that have same date together ..[image: the first picture]

i want table like that  [image: table i need]
every row that have same date group together i am tried group_concat and group_by but it not work i want some filter in php combine row that have same date together

my code :

```
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $start_res = strtotime($row['from_date']);
                            $end_res = strtotime($row['to_date']);
                            for ($res = $start_res; $res <= $end;$res+=86400) {
                                $res_date = date("m/d/Y", $res);
                                $startres = strtotime($res_date);

                                if ($startres >= $start_res && $startres<=$end_res) {
                      ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?= $res_date ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['1'] ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['2'] ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['3'] ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['4'] ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['5'] ?> </td>
                                        <td><?= $row['6'] ?> </td>
                                        <td>0 </td>
                                        <td style="background-color:gold"> 0</td>
                                        <td>0 </td>        
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
        <?php }}}?>
```

my table :[image: mysqli table]
sql query :

```
       $sql = "
         SELECT * FROM  mytable
        WHERE hotel_id = '" . $hotel_id . "'          
        and from_date  between '" . $date . "' and '" . $end_date . "'
        or to_date  between '" . $date . "' and '" . $end_date . "'
        ORDER BY from_date asc

        ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Comment: What efforts have you made in this attempt? Show us the relevant code, what code you have tried (even if it isn't working)

Comment: You can generate an array with date as index. But what have you tried?

Comment: As @SougataBose mentioned: (1) read all the data from MySQL and loop trough it, (2) create a multidimensional array with 'date' as first index, (3) create a new table with the contents of your array... an advanced version might be a single MySQL query

Comment: i edit my question and insert my code

Comment: i want something like when the date from loop equal to the date from db >combine row together like second picture

Comment: do u have example @mixable

Comment: Can you show us your table structure and query, it's probably easier to solve this in SQL than PHP

Comment: @Nick i edit my question and put my table and query

Comment: So it's more an output thing, not an update of the current table? Sorry, I do not have an example... but @Nick already provided a good answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table structure, it is probably simplest to do this in PHP. To do it in SQL would require a calendar table to JOIN to each row. So you need to aggregate values for each date and then output them. Note I prefer to work with the column names as array indexes as it's easier to see what you're doing:

```
$data = array();
// collate the data
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $start_res = strtotime($row['from_date']);
    $end_res = strtotime($row['to_date']);
    for ($res = $start_res; $res <= $end && $res <= $end_res; $res += 86400) {
        if (!isset($data[$res])) $data[$res] = array('totals' => 0, 'agent' => 0, 'direct' => 0, 'over_agent' => 0, 'over_hotel' => 0, 'allotment' => 0);
        $data[$res]['totals'] += $row['totals'];
        $data[$res]['agent'] += $row['agent'];
        $data[$res]['direct'] += $row['direct'];
        $data[$res]['over_agent'] += $row['over_agent'];
        $data[$res]['over_hotel'] += $row['over_hotel'];
        $data[$res]['allotment'] += $row['allotment'];
    }
}
// sort the data by date
ksort($data);
// now display the combined data
foreach ($data as $res_date => $row) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?= date('m/d/Y', $res_date) ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['totals'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['agent'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['direct'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['over_agent'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['over_hotel'] ?> </td>
    <td><?= $row['allotment'] ?> </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td style="background-color:gold"> 0</td>
    <td>0 </td>        
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: finally thanx alot @Nick it wooork i try to  solve this about a week ... i love u man :) :)